# Let $f_j :X_j \to Y_j$ be maps. Show that if the product map $f : X \to Y$ is continuous then every $f_j$ must be continuos also.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological product spaces and let $f_j :X_j \to Y_j$ be maps. Show that if the product $$\prod_j f_j :  X \to Y$$ is continuous then every $f_j$ must be continuous.

I didn’t find the definition for $\prod_j f_j $, but I suppose this is just the map $f = (f_1,f_2, \dots)$ which maps $x$ to $(f_1(x_1), f_2(x_2), \dots)$.

By the universal property of product spaces if the map $f=\prod_j f_j  $ is continuous then the maps $f_j = \pi_j \circ f$ are continuous as the composition of two continuos maps?

Comment: It suffices to prove this for binary products, since one could always write an arbitrary product as a binary product of one of the factors and the product of the other factors.

Comment: I think the proof is fine.

Comment: @Trebor $\pi_j \circ f \neq f_j$, mind you. The domains are diffent.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a fixed $p_j, j \in J$ in $\prod_{j \in J} X_j$.

Then for each fixed $j_0 \in J$ the injection $e_{j_0}: X_{j_0} \to \prod_{j \in J} X_j$ defined by $e_{j_0}(x)_j = x$ for $j=j_0$ and $e_{j_0}(x)_j = p_j$ for $j \neq j_0$ is continuous by the universal property for products.

Then $f_{j_0} = \pi_{j_0} \circ \prod_{j \in J} f_j  \circ e_{j_0}$ is continuous whenever the product map is, for each $j_0 \in J$.